# PHP Contactform with confirmation email

Tags: php, html, email

I made a contactform which send (if filled in) a mail to the email that's in the code. I want a contactform that send a confirmation email to the person that fills in the form AND to the owner of the site. So the customer knows he filled in the form in the site.
If this makes any sense? I dont know how to explain it better.

**CODE:** **Index.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once 'helpers/security.php';

$errors = isset($_SESSION['errors']) ? $_SESSION['errors'] : [];
$fields = isset($_SESSION['fields']) ? $_SESSION['fields'] : [];
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Contact form</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="contact">

    <?php if(!empty($errors)): ?>
        <div class="panel">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <?php echo implode('</li><li>', $errors); ?>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <?php  endif; ?>
    <form action="contact.php" method="post">
        <label>
            Your name*
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" autocomplete="off" <?php echo isset($fields['name']) ? 'Value="' . e($fields['name']) . '"' : '' ?>>
        </label>
        <label>
            Your email address *
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" autocomplete="off" <?php echo isset($fields['email']) ? 'Value="' . e($fields['email']) . '"' : '' ?>>
        </label>
        <label>
            Your message *
            <textarea name="message" id="contact" rows="8"><?php echo isset($fields['message']) ? e($fields['message']) : '' ?></textarea>
        </label>

        <input type="submit" value="Send">

        <p class="muted">* Means a required field</p>
    </form>
</div>



</body>
</html>

<?php
unset($_SESSION['errors']);
unset($_SESSION['fields']);
?>
```

**CODE: contact.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once "libs/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";

$errors = [];


if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['message'])) {

$fields = [
    'name' => $_POST['name'],
    'email' => $_POST['email'],
    "message" => $_POST['message']
];

foreach($fields as $field => $data) {
    if(empty($data)){
        $errors[] = 'The ' . $field . ' field is required.';
    }
}

    // 587 is voor uitgaande email deze is SSL en SMTP.ziggo.nl
    // 993 is voor inkomende email deze is TLS en IMAP.ziggo.nl
    // 110 is voor inkomende email deze is POP3 en
if(empty($errors)){
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

    $mail->Host = '';
    $mail->Username = '';
    $mail->Password = '';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port = 587;

    $mail->isHTML();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

    $mail->Subject = 'Subject';
    $mail->Body = 'From: ' . $fields['name'] . ' ('. $fields['email'] .') <p>'. $fields['message'] .'</p>';

    $mail->FromName = $fields['name'];

    $mail->AddAddress('rainier.laan@home.nl', 'Rainier Laan');

    if($mail->send()){
        header('Location: bedankt.php');
        die();
    } else {
        echo $mail->ErrorInfo; exit;
    }
}

} else {
$errors[] = 'Something went wrong.';
}

$_SESSION['errors'] = $errors;
$_SESSION['fields'] = $fields;

header('location: index.php');
```

I hope you guys can help me out with this and can provide me with code i can use. If something i said are unclear please say so. This code is without this function that i explained above, This is only with the function that the owner gets a mail not the customer. Rainier laan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code for contact.php

```
<?php

    session_start();

    require_once "libs/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";

    $errors = [];


    if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['message'])) {

    $fields = [
        'name' => $_POST['name'],
        'email' => $_POST['email'],
        "message" => $_POST['message']
    ];

    foreach($fields as $field => $data) {
        if(empty($data)){
            $errors[] = 'The ' . $field . ' field is required.';
        }
    }

        // 587 is voor uitgaande email deze is SSL en SMTP.ziggo.nl
        // 993 is voor inkomende email deze is TLS en IMAP.ziggo.nl
        // 110 is voor inkomende email deze is POP3 en
    if(empty($errors)){
        $mail = new PHPMailer;

        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

        $mail->Host = '';
        $mail->Username = '';
        $mail->Password = '';
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->Port = 587;

        $mail->isHTML();
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

        $mail->Subject = 'Someone filled in your contactform';
        $mail->Body = $fields['name'].' filled in your form with the following message: ' .$fields['message'];

        $mail->FromName = $fields['name'];

        $mail->AddAddress('rainier.laan@home.nl', 'Rainier Laan'); //added mail id of owner

        if($mail->send()){

            $mail = new PHPMailer;

            $mail->isSMTP();
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

            $mail->Host = '';
            $mail->Username = '';
            $mail->Password = '';
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
            $mail->Port = 587;

            $mail->isHTML();
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

            $mail->Subject = 'Confirmation contactform';
            $mail->Body = 'Thank you for filling in our form.<br> Message: <p>'. $fields['message'] .'</p>';

            $mail->FromName = 'Owner';

            $mail->AddAddress($fields['email] , $fields['name]); //added mail id of user
            if($mail->send()){
                header('Location: bedankt.php');
                die();
            }
            else{
                exit;
            }
        } else {
            echo $mail->ErrorInfo; exit;
        }
    }

    } else {
    $errors[] = 'Something went wrong.';
    }

    $_SESSION['errors'] = $errors;
    $_SESSION['fields'] = $fields;

    header('location: index.php');
```

Comment: I think this could work. The only thing is that i can't try this today because the email data that i filled in from my provider i too protected or something because it gives me a big error. Maybe you guys know what to do? I know you can get around that error because i did it before. Here is the error: http://prntscr.com/daf4jc

Comment: @RainierLaan feel free raise new question.

Comment: I doesnt work. the code that you provided only sends an email to the mail that the user fills in. Not to both my personal and the users email. What it does is, it sends an email to the users email FROM my personal email that is in the code. (If you read carefully you'll understand) And also to my personal email. Can you help me out?

Comment: Thank you it workes now! I stuggled with this for ages! Thank you so very much!

Comment: I have a question? Is there a possible way to customize the email send to the customer? So the email that the user recieves is diffrent then that from the owner? Something like this: The user recieved a email with the subjet "Confirmation contactform" but the owner recieve the subjet "Someone filled in your contactform". But also with the content in the mail. So the user gets "Thank you for filling in our form". And the owner gets "[name] filled in your form with the following message: [message]". Is this possible? @GopalPatel

Comment: I got it working just like i wanted to. But it gives me an error, And i think it has something to do with the redirect when the form is send. Here is the error: http://prntscr.com/db5vt8 Do you know how to fix this? What i want is just on the same screen as the form a message that says it has been send. So no redirect to another page. @GopalPatel